# App finding out which day it ism and calculating time towards the next day which user selects

Tags: ios, swift, date

So far, I have this code:

```
var seconds = 0
var minutes = 0
var hours = 0


var secondsUntilMidnight = 0
 var minutesUntilMidnight = 0
 var hoursUntilMidnigh = 0
var day = 0
var month = 0
 var year = 0
 //xvar day = [ hours, minutes, seconds]

 var damian = "DayofWeek"

var monday = true
var tuesday = false
var wednesday = true
var thursday = false
var friday = false
var saturday = true
var sunday = false
var  currentDay = 0
var nextworkingday = 0
var dayOfTheWeek = [Bool]()///Var collecting bools for each day
var dayOfTheWeekText = [String]()///Collecing name for each day
where the weekday Bool values are adjustable. I want the app to detect the current time and date, and calculate the time until the next day that is set as true.

This is what I have tried so far:


   let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar,    hour:11  , minute : 28 )  // <- 17:00 = 5pm
    // let  components2 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar day : 1, _)
    let next5pm = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    print (now )
    let next  = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!


    let diff = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second ], from: now, to: next5pm)

    ///Second time checker
    let calendar2 = Calendar.current
    let components2 = DateComponents(calendar: calendar2,    hour:00   , minute : 00 )  // <- 17:00 = 5pm
    let next1pm = calendar2.nextDate(after: now, matching: components2, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!

    let next2  = calendar2.nextDate(after: now, matching: components2, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!


    let diff2 = calendar2.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second ], from: now, to: next1pm)
    secondsUntilMidnight = diff2.second!
    minutesUntilMidnight = diff2.minute!
    hoursUntilMidnigh = diff2.hour!

    hours = diff.hour!
    minutes = diff.minute!
    seconds = diff.second!
```

But it only calculates the time until a certain time the NEXT day while I want it to detect. For example, if today is Monday, and the next day is Wednesday and start a countdown to a seleced time on that day.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Update
Ignore the code, its just an example of what i have done to try to give the app the functionality that is needed!
In this viewport, i want the code to check what day it is, see when another day that is 'true' and calculate time until then

Comment: Next time, please edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029814/ios-count-down-until-next-selected-day-in-hours-minutes-seconds) instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Swift date has a method [timeIntervalSince](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince) which will calculate the TimeInterval (ie number of seconds) between two dates.  You can then use [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) to transform the interval into a formatted string containing whatever units you want.

Comment: Josh, so far the help from apple developer website is....too informational and doesn't help me much, any way you can help?  any good tutorials? searched stuff online etc